# Вставка фото вместо узлов графа в Rstudio, с помощью библиотеки visNetwork

Tags: изображения, r

Всем привет, такой вопрос: я хочу вставить картинки вместо узлов на графе.Использую библиотеку visNetwork на движке vis.js. Нашел статью https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/image_icon.html, с описанием как это сделать, но у меня ничего не вырисовывается в Rstudio.

```
path_to_images <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datastorm-open/datastorm-open.github.io/master/visNetwork/data/img/indonesia/"

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:4, 
                shape = c("image", "circularImage"),
                image = paste0(path_to_images, 1:4, ".png"),
                label = "I'm an image")

edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,4,3,3), to = c(1,2,4,2))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
   visNodes(shapeProperties = list(useBorderWithImage = TRUE)) %>%
   visLayout(randomSeed = 2)
```

Вместо path_to_images я вставил локальную директорию, в которой лежат все картинки, формата png:

```
setwd("/home/user/")
path_to_images<-"Images/"
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:4, 
                shape = c("image", "circularImage"),
                image = paste0(path_to_images, 1:4, ".png"),
                label = "I'm an image")

edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,4,3,3), to = c(1,2,4,2))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
   visNodes(shapeProperties = list(useBorderWithImage = TRUE)) %>%
   visLayout(randomSeed = 2)
```

Comment: `file.exists(paste0(path_to_images, 1:4, ".png"))`?

Answer (score 0):

После того, как я поднял у себя apache2 и выложил там в директории http://localhost/Images картинки, затем поменял переменную path_to_images, у меня все заработало.